# Parse - callback functions skipped

Tags: ios, callback, parse-platform

I'm experiencing some issues with parse at the moment. I think that parse skips every callback.

```
user.password = _textfeld_Passwort.text;
user.email = _textfeld_email.text;

NSLog(@"next: signUp");

[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"signUp started");
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"no error!");
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"succes");
            UIAlertView *succes = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erfolgreich!" message:@"Registrierung abgeschlossen! Bitte bestätige den Link in der Email, die wir an dich gesendet haben! Und logge dich dann ein!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [succes show];

            [self initialerStundenplan];

            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"registriert"];
            [defaults setObject:_textfeld_Username.text forKey:@"Username"];
            [defaults setObject: Stufe_temp forKey:@"Stufe"];
            [defaults setObject:_textfeld_Passwort.text forKey:@"Passwort"];

            [defaults synchronize];
            _button_Login.hidden = NO;
            [self viewDidLoad];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"no succes!");
            UIAlertView *fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehlgeschlagen!1" message:@"Bitte versuche es erneut!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [fail show];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error!");
        UIAlertView *fail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehlgeschlagen!2" message:@"Bitte versuche es erneut!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [fail show];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"completed / skipped");
```

}

I've built in some outputs. Here's the console output:

```
2015-01-01 20:01:05.901 Vertretungsplan[5535:2195125] next: signUp
2015-01-01 20:01:05.905 Vertretungsplan[5535:2195125] completed / skipped
```

So can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong or is it a Parse bug? I'm using the Parse iOS SDK 1.6.1.

Comment: do you keep a pointer to user?

Comment: Hm... a lot of people have been posting since yesterday about weird Parse callback behavior...

Comment: I suspect a bug, but how are you declaring and initializing `user`?

Comment: Time, PFUser *user will declare the user, but not initialize it. Have you actually initialized the user somewhere? If not, then you are likely pointing to nowhere (i.e. garbage data or nil) and so your method call ("message" in Objective-C I believe it is officially called) is being ignored. Can you post how/where you declare and initialize the user. Once you do that we can probably give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I declare & initialize it with: `PFUser * user; user = [PFUser user];` (like it is shown in the docs:(https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-signup/iOS))

Comment: Hmm, sorry about the late reply, wasn't at my computer much today. Are you never getting any output from the callback? It should still occur after "completed/skipped" because the thread is running asynchronously, but it seems like it should be executing properly.

Comment: Oh! One other thing, try setting the username property of your user first. I.e. user.username = @"Test"; (using a string here instead of a custom variable will make this only go through once because you can't have multiple users with the same username, but you do have to have a username for signUpInBackgroundWithBlock to execute properly: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:)